# How to delete markers from timeline

Tags: animation, timeline

How do you select and delete markers in the time line once created in Blender 3.0? I tried box selecting and x to delete. Can't do either.
[image]

Comment: I've just tried in a simple file and both worked.  Can you strip a blend file down to one that just shows the problem and add it to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I uploaded the .blend and the markers are at the bottom on the graph editor and it's the same on the time line.

Answer (score 2):

You have locked the markers.  One way to fix this is to go to the *Dope Sheet* editor, select the *Marker* menu and deselect *Mark Markers*

[image: Dope Sheet Marker menu with Lock Markers highlighted.]

Or you can also fix it in the Marker Menus of the timeline:

[image]